# Zabbix - Alert if any files in folder is older than 1hr

Tags: windows, zabbix

I have a folder which holds files that are to be processed. Once they are processed, they are then moved to another directory.

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to monitor for files inside this directory and alert if there are any files that are older than 1hr. i.e. They have not been processed yet.

In Zabbix, you can use vfs.file.time item but this only monitors 1 file and you have to specify the name of the file as well. The names inside the folder I'm monitoring are irrelevant.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably need to write a UserParameter. I can't think of anything built-in that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if it can work with files like you're describing, but you might be able to setup LLD (Low Level Discovery).

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery

Comment: I think LLD could work but it would then treat each file as an item instead of a text value.

Comment: But that was the whole point right?

After discovering all the files, you are then able to create a prototype trigger to check the timestamp on the files, and send an alert if it exceeds 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

The "cleanest" way would probably a [`UserParameter`](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/items/userparameters) in your agent config  or the use of [Remote Commands](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command). Simply write a script with the desired output, or - even simpler - just use `find ./ -type f -mmin +60 | wc -l` for example and check for output `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Zabbix-agent's `vfs.dir.count`:

> vfs.dir.count[dir, <regex_incl>, <regex_excl>, <types_incl>,
> <types_excl>,<max_depth>, <min_size>, <max_size>, **<min_age>**,
> <max_age>, <regex_excl_dir>]

**min_age** - minimum age (in seconds) of directory entry to be counted. More recent entries will not be counted